# Why is JSP view not being resolved?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to deploy a Spring web app on Tomcat 7.0.42 with Servlet 3.0. The default home of the app is opening fine, but when I try to navigate from the home, I am getting a 404. Please find details below.

My servlet-contex.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.portfolio.chota" />

</beans:beans>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Do some stuff          
            return "home";
    }


@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String profile(Locale locale, Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {    
        String pAge = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("SAVINGSAMOUNTTYPE");
        if(pAge==null || pAge.equals(""))
            return "redirect:/sessionOut";
        else
            return "profile";
    }
```

When I access the app the home is loading fine, but when I try to move to /profile from the home, I am getting the following 404

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36 404 /abc/profile
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I found out the problem was with the **cp_jkmount.conf** file in these locations -

1. /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/**xyz/domain.com**/
2. /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/ssl/2/**xyz/domain.com**/

Here **xyz** is the user & **domain.com** is the domain for which you are trying to set this.

This was set to mount *.jsp & *.do files such that requests with these extensions were only being sent to the Tomcat daemon. Since ours is a Spring app without any extension in its requests that's why those requests were not being served to Tomcat.

These were the original entries in cp_jkmount.conf

```
JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
JkMount /*.do ajp13
```

I have now updated this to

```
JkMount /* ajp13
```

Since this domain hosts only pure java based apps, thats why all my requests are now served to Tomcat & thus my problem has been resolved.

Hope this helps someone of you too.

Comment: Do you have a handler for `/sessionOut`?

Comment: you have /WEB-INF/VIEWS/profile.jsp available in war?

Comment: @AliDehghani Yes there is a handler for /sessionOut.

Comment: @Pulkit Yeah the jsp pages are there in the war

Comment: Add two things to your post [1] the **full** URL you use to launch the home page [2] The **full** URL which the link on the home page points to.

Comment: Changing url-pattern "/" to "/*" in your `web.xml` maybe helps?

Comment: I reached your homepage when the address was http://www.tunespray.com/. What I'm guessing is that in web.xml url-pattern of appServlet should be /mini/*

Comment: @JulianL Neither /* or /mini/* is working.

Comment: @PallavJha Neither /* or /mini/* is working